# Changing Order For First Responders in SwiftUI TextFields

Tags: swiftui, focus, textfield

I am working on a crossword app.

I have a SquareView that contains a Text and TextField, to show the number and letter for a particular square.

A 2D array of those SquareViews forms the grid of the puzzle.

I can navigate back and forth horizontally through the TextFields using the tab key, and all the highlighting works (current square yellow, adjacent answer squares blue, all others white or black).

My problem arises when I want to toggle navigation, to move vertically. I **thought** that  the order in which TextFields were navigated depended on the order in which they were added, so I toggled between a VStack of HStacks (across clues, running horizontally) and HStack of VStacks (for down clues, running vertically). Nope. SwiftUI **always** moves from left-to-right, top-to-bottom. How can I change this? I learned from this forum about Introspect, so I can access each TextField's underlying UITextField and change ... it's color , but that's not what I need. I need to be able to change order in which first responders are chosen.

Any assistance would be most welcome!

Comment: I have this issue also, I tried adding an `.id(number)` modifier with the order I want, but without result. In my case the focus order doesn't depend on the order the views are drawn, is aleatory, so is a lot annoying.

Comment: I just gave up and went back to using UIKit -- I know that SwiftUI is awesome and all, but I was spending too much time fighting the technology. I'll go back to it when more functionality and documentation (!!) are in place.